# tx_news and realURL

Tags: typo3, realurl, tx-news

i got a problem. I am using tx_news (1.13.3) together with realURL. For some reason the searchform and datemenu don't work together with realURL. Searchform doesn't work at all = getting 404 when submitting search request. And Datemenu lists all months but when i click on a month to get the listview i get a 404. The items "listview" and "detailview" are working fine. Additionally I ve set up a local test-enviroment with the same typo3 installation but deactivated realURL and for some reason it worked fine (listview from the datemenu AND searchform). Does anybody know whats wrong and/or missing in the realURL config to get this also working with realURL??
TIA for your time.

This is my realURL config for tx_news:

```
        // EXT:news start
        'news' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                    'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                    'id_field' => 'uid',
                    'alias_field' => 'title',
                    'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                        'strtolower' => 1,
                        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                    ),
                    'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                    'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                    'autoUpdate' => 1,
                    'expireDays' => 180,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // EXT:news end
```

Comment: Can you post the html from the searchform? When I watch at my searchform I see that post-method is used. So realURl have nothing to do with it. + Can you reporduce the error on your test-enviroment when realURL is enabled?

Comment: I ve deactivated realURL in my production-enviroment and now searchform + datemenu->listview are working fine. So the problem is with realURL, but i can not figure out what s missing exactly..

Comment: can you post the URL with and without realURL`?

Comment: With realURL(leads to 404): http://info.local.dev/alle-nachrichten/hs/1bda9d163294427fa6a71fb6c8fc2c1e/news//News/?tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]=2015&tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]=06

without realURL(works fine): http://info.local.dev/index.php?id=1290&tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]=2015&tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]=06&tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&cHash=1bda9d163294427fa6a71fb6c8fc2c1e

Comment: Hmm I think there is a problem with the cHash. the cHash gets into your URL as `hs`. Search in your realURL config for something like `'hs' => array(` and remove that for testing.

Comment: you were right. after commenting out the the hs array, i got the searchform and datemenu working.. so i still got a nice URL even without the ugly cHash. Thanks alot. you can put this info into an answer so i am able to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your comment you created a realURL config for the cHash `'hs' => array(`.

remove that array and it should work.